# Trying to Loop through Redshift Records for Updates

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have about 2.5 million records which are considered interactions of potential marketing leads.  For the purposes of clearly defining when a new interaction starts, we have some rules.  If a lead of type Q comes in more than 30 days after the last valid acquisition, then it is valid.  If it comes in less than 30 days after the last valid acquisition it is considered a duplicate.  Same logic above for lead type C and 60 days.  A lead could come in as type C and Q for the same lead/phone number.

What I'm trying to do is traverse through the table starting Mar 1, 2022 and determine which records are VALID and which are DUPLICATE.  The first occurrence of each "phone" in this date range is VALID and I have already populate the field "new_status" for these first occurrences as "VALID". I am trying to determine duplicate or valid for any interaction after that 1st interaction

I've mostly worked in SQL Server previously and could accomplish this with a combination of a cursor and a while loop.  Not ideal for performance, but that's how I could make it work.

Redshift doesn't appear to be as robust.  I'm attempting to do a while loop in a stored procedure to do this, but am open to any type of solution in redshift.  This is a one-time analysis but may be something that runs frequently for new acquisitions.

Here is the proc I tried to create, but I get a result of

```
ERROR [3:1]:(SQLSTATE: 42601, SQLCODE: 0): ERROR: syntax error at or near "as" Where: SQL statement in PL/PgSQL function "dupe_loop" near line 33
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE public.dupe_loop()
^
```

I'm sure syntax is wrong, probably where I am trying to declare the variable as a result of the query.  Open to any suggestions on how to handle.

`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE public.dupe_loop()
as $$

declare
  nullcnt INTEGER;

BEGIN
  WHILE
    nullcnt > 0
    LOOP
    
    nullcnt := (SELECT COALESCE(COUNT(*),0) FROM rge.dupe_check_leads WHERE new_status)
    ;

    UPDATE public.dupe_check_leads
    SET new_status = 
      CASE 
        WHEN L2.source = 'Q' AND DATEDIFF('day',L1.startdate_human, L2.startdate_human) > 30 THEN 'VALID'
        WHEN L2.source = 'C' AND DATEDIFF('day',L1.startdate_human, L2.startdate_human) > 60 THEN 'VALID'
        ELSE 'DUPE'
      END as New_Status
    FROM (SELECT phone, acq_id, stardate_human, RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY phone ORDER BY startdate_human DESC) as rank_num
          FROM public.dupe_check_leads 
          WHERE new_status = 'VALID'
          ) L1
        INNER JOIN 
          (SELECT phone, acq_id, stardate_human, RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY phone ORDER BY startdate_human ASC) as rank_num
            FROM public.dupe_check_leads
            WHERE new_status IS NULL
          ) L2
          ON L2.phone = L1.phone
          AND L2.rank_num = 1
        INNER JOIN public.dupe_check_leads a
          ON a.acq_id = L2.acq_id
    WHERE L1.rank_num = 1
    ;
  END LOOP;

END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

```
Example Inputs below.  "New_Status" field is desired outcome.

Phone    startdate_human    Source        New_Status
123      3/1/2022           C             VALID
123      3/2/2022           C             DUPE
123      4/2/2022           Q             VALID
123      5/15/2022          C             DUPE
123      6/5/2022           C             VALID
```

UPDATE:
Thanks for pointing out the "AS new_status" in the update statement.  Once I removed that, I was able to proceed.  There were some additional edits needed though.  Here is the final query.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE public.dupe_loop()
as $$

declare
  nullcnt INTEGER := 999999 ;

BEGIN
  WHILE
    nullcnt > 0
    LOOP
    


    UPDATE public.dupe_check_leads
    SET new_status =
      CASE 
        WHEN L2.source = 'Q' AND DATEDIFF('day',L1.startdate_human, L2.startdate_human) > 30 THEN 'VALID'
        WHEN L2.source = 'C' AND DATEDIFF('day',L1.startdate_human, L2.startdate_human) > 60 THEN 'VALID'
        ELSE 'DUPE'
      END
    FROM (SELECT phone, acq_id, startdate_human, l.source, RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY phone ORDER BY startdate_human DESC) as rank_num
          FROM public.dupe_check_leads l
          WHERE new_status = 'VALID'
          ) L1
        INNER JOIN 
          (SELECT phone, acq_id, startdate_human, l.source, RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY phone ORDER BY startdate_human ASC) as rank_num
            FROM public.dupe_check_leads l
            WHERE new_status IS NULL
          ) L2
          ON L2.phone = L1.phone
          AND L2.rank_num = 1
        INNER JOIN public.dupe_check_leads a
          ON a.acq_id = L2.acq_id
    WHERE L1.rank_num = 1
    ;

    nullcnt = (SELECT COALESCE(COUNT(*),0) FROM public.dupe_check_leads WHERE new_status IS NULL)
    ;

  END LOOP;

END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Why doesn't the line in your error message appear in your query?

Comment: Coginiti can be funny about how it reports errors.  I had the code highlighted I was running, but there were queries above it, so that error wasn't useful.

I've updated the post to show the actual error.   Thank you.

Comment: I think your error is that you are using `new_status = [...] AS new_status`. You should remove the `AS new_status`.

Comment: the update clause cvan not have  `As new_stautus` remove it

Comment: Thank you.  The AS new_status was the problem holding me up.  After removing it, I got past that error and discovered a whole bunch of new errors, but was able to resolve them.  I will update the original post and add the final query.

Thanks again.